# Adding SSL certificate to Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy

I am working with BrowserMob-Proxy and Selenium. Loading pretty much any URL results in a `Your connection is not secure, Error code:SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` error in the browser. However, when I import the  [certificate given by BMP](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/mitm/README.md) (via Firefox->Options->Advanced->Certificates->Import), everything works smoothly.

My question is how to do this programmatically. I have already tried

```
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
```

but that doesn't seem to have any affect at all. Any way to to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new firefox profile "sslProfile". See firefox help for your OS.

In your selenium code:

```
ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni()                
FirefoxProfile foxProfile= prof.getProfile ("sslProfile")

foxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true) 
foxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false)

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver (foxProfile)
```

Comment: Ah, I did not realize the profile had to be made manually, _then retrieved_ through the code. Works perfect, thanks!